# OpenCart when clicking view order it loads a blank page

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, orders

I am using opencart for an online shop I am creating.

When I look at the latest orders section I am supposed to be able to click view for each order.

When the view link is clicked all that is loaded is a blank page.

There are no errors that I can see. I can provide any code you need however I do not know where the error is so help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding to following to the top of your admin/index.php file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors" , 1);
```

This should give you more information about the bug.